# Why is Scottish BSc (Hons) 4 years while English BSc (Hons) is 3 years?

Tags: masters, undergraduate, degree, united-kingdom

Why BSc (Hons) in Scotland (in Computer Science but in other subjects probably too) is 4 years long and in England BSc (Hons) is 3 years long? Does it cover more material? Does it mean that MSc in Scotland is shorter than in England? In general, how long is MSc in these countries? Is it 1 years or 2 years?

Comment: @Davidmh Really? Aren't they usually 1 in both? For example: http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/admissions/msc_computer_science/

Comment: @Davidmh Most Master programs in the UK I know are only 1 year.

Comment: Yes, my Scottish taught MSc was a year

Comment: This is the UK we're talking about.  Does there need to be an explanation beyond "That's how we've always done it"?

Answer (score 2):

In Scotland, you can attend university after completing Highers, which are taken in the same year as AS levels are taken in England. Therefore, many Scottish students leave school a year earlier. Theoretically, the first year of university in Scotland is less advanced than the first year of university in England (although speaking from experience, I don't believe that this is practically the case). In recognition of this fact, it is often possible for English students to [enter their course directly into second year, with a higher grade requirement](http://www.ed.ac.uk/studying/undergraduate/applying/ucas/second-year).

Comment: I have a vague recollection (from quite some time ago) that Scottish school-leavers who'd completed their sixth year (CSYS then, Advanced Higher now) could enter in the second year of university as well. The Edinburgh page suggests this is still the case but isn't very explicit on the matter. I never encountered someone who planned to do it, though...